# Docker build command fails to resolve domains

Tags: dns, docker-compose, apt

I set up a Debian 10 server to host my containers running on Docker version 19.03.2.

It currently hosts 3 DNS containers (pi-hole => bind9 => dnscrypt-proxy) which means my Debian 10 server acts as a DNS server for my LAN.
[image: docker ps -a]

I want to add a new container. However, I can't build it because it fails when it comes to RUN apt-get update. I checked the content of the /etc/resolv.conf of the container, and the content seems right (nameserver 1.1.1.1 and nameserver 9.9.9.9, that matches with what I wrote in /etc/docker/daemon.json).

If I'm correct, the build step uses - by default - the DNS of the host, except if you specify DNS servers in /etc/default/docker or /etc/docker/daemon.json.

If the DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf seem correct, and if the container has an Internet access (I tried a RUN ping 8.8.8.8 -c1 and it works), the build should succeed ?

I tried several things, like overwriting the content of /etc/resolv.conf with other DNS, I also rebooted the server, restarted Docker, pruned downloaded images, used the --no-cache option... I also reinstalled Docker. Nothing seems to work.

It must be somehow related to my DNS containers I guess.

Below is the content of the /etc/resolv.conf of the host (the first one is itself, as it redirects to Pi-hole).
[image: cat /etc/resolv.com (host)]

Have you any lead to solve this issue ?

I can provide the docker-compose file of my DNS containers and the Dockerfile of my new container if you need them.

Thanking you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I have found this fix :

RUN chmod o+r /etc/resolv.conf && apt-get [....]

It works when I change the permissions.

I do not really understand why it behaves like this, if you have any lead I would be glad to know more !